# Cannot bind slider value in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, slider, dependency-properties

I am trying to create a DataGrid with two text columns and a template column as follows:

```xml
<UserControl
   ...   
   Name="TcpNtcpSliders"
...>
<DataGrid Name="MinTcpDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="2" Grid.Row="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MinTcpRows, ElementName=TcpNtcpSliders, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Structure ID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto"
                                    Binding="{Binding StructureId, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Min. TCP" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" x:Name="MinTcpTextColumn"
                                    Binding="{Binding MinTcpValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Set Min. Tcp" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1"
                                    Value="{Binding MinTcpValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

In the code behind I have

```cs
internal ObservableCollection<MinTcpRow> MinTcpRows
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<MinTcpRow>)GetValue(MinTcpRowsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinTcpRowsProperty, value); }
        }

        internal static readonly DependencyProperty MinTcpRowsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MinTcpRows", typeof(ObservableCollection<MinTcpRow>),
                typeof(RtpOptimizationTcpNtcpSliders),
                new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<MinTcpRow>(), MinTcpRowsPropertyChangedCallback));

        private static void MinTcpRowsPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = (RtpOptimizationTcpNtcpSliders)d;
            control.MinTcpRows = (ObservableCollection<MinTcpRow>)e.NewValue;
            control.CreateTcpNtcpLimits();
        }
```

and the `MinTcpRow` class is defined like:

```cs
public class MinTcpRow
    {
        public string StructureId { get; }
        public double MinTcpValue { get; set; }

        public MinTcpRow(string structureId, double minTcpValue)
        {
            if (minTcpValue < 0 || minTcpValue > 1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(minTcpValue)} must " +
                                                      $"be in range [0, 1], but was {minTcpValue}.");
            StructureId = structureId ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(structureId));
            MinTcpValue = minTcpValue;
        }
}
```

Everything works as expected, except for the Slider value binding. I says `cannot resolve symbol 'MinTcpValue'`. How can I bind the slider's value correctly?

Comment: The way you do that observablecollection looks a bit odd. You're getting rows though?

Comment: MinTcpRow should implement inotifypropertychanged and if you want it MinTcpValue changes in there to be reflected in the view then you need to raise property changed in the setter of MinTcpValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see what happens I put a simplified version together.

In my mainwindow I have a datagrid:

```
    <DataGrid Name="MinTcpDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Structure ID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto"
                                Binding="{Binding StructureId, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Min. TCP" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" x:Name="MinTcpTextColumn"
                                Binding="{Binding MinTcpValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Set Min. Tcp" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1"
                                Value="{Binding MinTcpValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

MainWindowViewModel will supply my Rows collection:

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<MinTcpRow> rows = new ObservableCollection<MinTcpRow>();
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        rows.Add(new MinTcpRow ("A",0.1));
        rows.Add(new MinTcpRow("B", 0.5));
        rows.Add(new MinTcpRow("C", 0.9));
    }
}
```

And MinTcpRow ( is faulted because it won't notify change ) but looks the same.

```
public class MinTcpRow
{
    public string StructureId { get; }
    public double MinTcpValue { get; set; }

    public MinTcpRow(string structureId, double minTcpValue)
    {
        if (minTcpValue < 0 || minTcpValue > 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(minTcpValue)} must " +
                                                  $"be in range [0, 1], but was {minTcpValue}.");
        StructureId = structureId ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(structureId));
        MinTcpValue = minTcpValue;
```

And that works, no error anyhow.  There is a memory leak waiting to catch you out because of not implementing inpc but I get no error like you show us.  Are you somehow using a different version of MinTcpRow ?

[image]

Comment: Like this it works, thank you! However, it does not show the correct value in the Min Tcp DataGridTextColumn. Any idea why? I am using Prism properties instead of the [ObservableProperty] that you are using.

Comment: MinTcpValue is just a regular public property exactly like the code you show in your question @Anno